# Calculating pulse width (duty cycle) using stm32 DMA. Is it possible?

Tags: timer, stm32, microcontroller, pwm

I'm working on a project that a series of duty cycles must be measured. A sample of related waveforms is displayed below:

[image]

As you can see from the signal, the frequency is too high, and calculating it using bit functions is impossible. In controller's tech website [here](https://stackoverflow.com), they used the timer's input capture modes and rising-falling edges interrupts for calculating the difference between two captures of the timer.But this method is too slow and cannot fulfill our desires for high-frequency signals.
The other solution is to use DMA for fast transferring the capture data to the memory. But in STM32cubemx it is not possible to assigned two DMAs for two captuers of a timer as you can see below:

[image]

Could some one give me a suggestion for this issue?

Comment: if this part doesnt work then have you looked at other products from st and other companies?

Comment: I'd be looking for a sharp electrical engineer to code an FPGA for me.

Comment: What precision do you require thee duty cycle?  Start there.  If your part cannot interrupt fast enough to achieve it, then you need to choose a different, faster part, or as @andymango suggests, think about a hardware solution.

Answer (score 0):

Using the DMA channel is not likely to provide a good solution for fast signals since the memory buss is shared between the DMA controller and CPU, so predictable timing over the capture event time is not guaranteed. Also, the timing relationship between the DMA transfers and the external signal will be difficult to resolve. So I'd say "no" to your question.

With 16-bit timers that can run up to 120 MHz, the STM32 featured timers is your best choice. An 800kHz signal is not considered too fast for these critters! The trick is how you make use of the timers. You want to use the input capture mode. Capture several samples of logic high signal times, then average these numbers, do the same for logic low signal times, then add for total timer ticks, then multiply this by the timer tick period for the external signal period.